React native expo bare android flavors error
I configured my Expo project to run with different packages on my android phone. I want the packages com.myapp and com.myapp.dev.
When I execute this, the application is installed on my phone with the name myapp-dev, but I get an error at the end:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
367 actionable tasks: 28 executed, 339 up-to-date
CommandError: No development build (com.myapp) for this project is installed. Please make and install a development build on the device first.
I made the following configuration in the file android/app/build.gradle:
flavorDimensions "env"
productFlavors {
    development {
        dimension "env"
        applicationId "com.myapp.dev"
    }
    production {
        dimension "env"
        applicationId "com.myapp"
    }
}

I created a development folder in android/app/src/development and created the file AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <!-- OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS, REMOVE WHATEVER YOU DO NOT NEED -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->

  <queries>
    <!-- Support checking for http(s) links via the Linking API -->
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
  </queries>

  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.myapp.dev" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>

I also created the strings.xml file in android/app/src/development/res/values/strings.xml and added the following code:
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyApp-Dev</string>
</resources>

My app.config.js file looks like this:
const isDev = process.env.APP_ENV === "development";

console.log(`Running in ${isDev ? "development" : "production"} env`);

export default {
  name: isDev ? "MyApp (Dev)" : "MyApp",
  slug: isDev ? "myapp-dev" : "myapp",
  version: "0.0.1",
  ios: {
    bundleIdentifier: isDev ? "com.myapp.dev" : "com.myapp",
  },
  android: {
    package: isDev ? "com.myapp.dev" : "com.myapp",
  },
  extra: {
    env: isDev ? "development" : "production",
  },
};

I run the following command to build the project:
"android:dev": "APP_ENV=development expo run:android --variant developmentRelease --no-build-cache"

